# Hibernate - How to set sql-type by annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, blob

I have a file as a byte[] fileContent. My mySql-scheme is generated by Hibernate and by default hibernate sets the sql-type of fileContent to BLOB.

But a BLOB is not big enough for my files. I will need at least a MEDIUMBLOM or even a LONGBLOB.

But how can i annotate my field so that Hibernate will generate the scheme with my field as a LONGBLOB?
I have search google for 2 hours now without getting anything...

Shouldn't this be a so simple and common task that it should be documented somewhere??

Please help a frustrated programmer!!

```
@WhatAnnotationCanIUseToForceHibernateToMakeThisALONGBLOB????
private byte[] fileContent;
```

Comment: I don't think the one in your example will work `:P`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Have you tried

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "LONGBLOB")
private byte[] fileContent;
```

Comment: That's JPA, not Hibernate (still probably the correct answer, but worth mentioning)