# Using BigInteger as primary key in Spring JPA gives - Incorrect column specifier for column 'id'

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want to have an infinitive primary key and that is `BigInteger`.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html

```
BIGINT[(M)] [UNSIGNED]  BIGINT [UNSIGNED]   java.lang.Long, if UNSIGNED java.math.BigInteger
```

So I created my `entity`

```
public class Alarm {

    // ID
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private BigInteger id;
```

And when I create the tables, I get the following error.

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table alarm (id decimal(19,2) not null auto_increment, frequencyp0p1p2 integer not null, frequencyp3p7p8 integer not null, frequencyp4 integer not null, frequencyp6p5 integer not null, port_description varchar(255), primary key (id)) engine=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Incorrect column specifier for column 'id'
```

So what have gone wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`BIGINT` is the same as a Java `Long`, not a `BigInteger`.

The question even quoted that, so use `Long`, not `BigInteger`, which Hibernate seems to want to map to `decimal(19,2)`, and that data type cannot be an auto-generated value.

---

***UPDATE:*** As mentioned by dunni in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65658600/using-biginteger-as-primary-key-in-spring-jpa-gives-incorrect-column-specifier/65658642?noredirect=1#comment116088771_65658642), you can force Hibernate to use the `BIGINT` data type with the `@Column` annotation:

```java
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(columnDefinition = "BIGINT")
private BigInteger id;
```

Comment: Ok. So MySQL can use BigInterger, but not Hibernate?

Comment: It can, but you need to tell Hibernate, that it must generate the column as BIGINT, not as DECIMAL, e.g. like mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081044/hibernate-how-to-set-sql-type-by-annotation